# Inserting record into a relational table with a foreign key?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express

I have two related tables with a one to many relationship:

`envelopes`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE envelopes (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('envelope_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL,
    budget integer NOT NULL
);
```

`transaction`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('transaction_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    envelope_id integer REFERENCES envelopes(id),
    date date NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL,
    amount integer NOT NULL
);
```

Each transaction will be attached to an envelope and at the same time, remove/add the quantity from the envelopes budget.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to write this query in Express.js but having trouble coming up with it.

I have the following in mind in POST for `/envelopes/:id/transactions`:

```js
...
        const sql = "INSERT INTO transactions(title, amount, date, envelope_id)VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *";

  try {
    const newTransaction = await db.query(sql, [title, amount, date, id]);
    res.status(201).send(newTransaction.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({
            error: err.message
        });
  }
...
```

Not sure if this is the appropiate way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try creating a Transaction, so either all the Queries gets executed or none.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO transactions (title, amount, date, envelope_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4);

UPDATE envelopes SET
    budget = budget - <Deduction Value>
    WHERE id = <envelope ID>;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```